# bootstrap tabs are not working when added via AJAX in a modal

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-tabs

I am using bootstrap 3.2.0 and encouter the following problem:
On my main page, I have a button. A click to this button opens a modal window. The modal window makes an API call and fills it's content-div with the respond of the AJAX-call.
The AJAX call returns something like this:

```
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="tabsFromAjax">
<li class="active"><a href="#one" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">ONE</a></li>
<li><a href="#two" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">TWO</a></li>
<li><a href="#three" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">THREE</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="one">this is tab 1</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="two">this is tab 2</div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="three">this is tab 3</div>
</div>

<script>
$("#tabsFromAjax").tab();
</script>
```

However, the tabs are not working. Clicking on "TWO" does change the tab itself - meaning the upper part - but will not show the content: "this is tab 2" on the bottom.
I tried everything I could think of. Now I start to wonder whether this is kind of a bug in 3.2.0 ?

**EDIT/UPDATE:**
I found out that even a simple binding does not work inside the modal. I try to show in code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="formView" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Detail" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".formShow").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: { id: 123 }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            $(".modal-content").html(msg);
            $("#formView").modal();
        });
    });
});
-->
</script>
```

And the AJAX-call to test.php simply returns this:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="testAnker">Foo</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#testAnker").click(function(){
        alert("click");
    });
</script>
```

Clicking on "Foo" does not show an alert.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I want to add that everything works fine if I do not use an AJAX call, but call the modal with the "remote" option. (Everything else is the same)

Comment: I want to also note that I just tried the same code inside a jQueryUI-Dialog-window and it works. So it seems that inside a bootstrap modal window it is not possible to run jQuery code.

Comment: Yes you can use jquery inside a bootstrap modal. Just so you know most bootstrap javascript components are jquery based. It is that you are trying to bind to Dom elements that do not yet exist.  I'll do a fiddle for you when I get in to work in a couple hours. Hang tight.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#tabsFromAjax").tab();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Put the click event listener in your Ajax done callback

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when you pull in new data through the ajax.  That the tabs "id" is different then either what you started with or what the next ajax call comes in with and try rebinding the tab's to the new id.

If you don't you may end up rebinding the tabs to the first element that had already been bound to.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".formShow").click(function(){
        var mid = 123;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            data: { id: mid }
        }).done(function( msg ) {
            $(".modal-content").html(msg);
            $("#formView").modal();
            $("#tabsFromAjax-"+mid).tab(); // this line key.
        });
    });
});
</script>
```